# Delay when using Stream.ReadByte()

Tags: c#, tcp

I am reading variable sized data from a tcpClient via NetworkStream.

Here is the code:

```
  public void ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF(NetworkStream tcpStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: " + LbTime.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("F0"));
        List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();
        while (true )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: " + LbTime.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("F0"));

            while (!tcpStream.CanRead)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            int abyte = tcpStream.ReadByte();
            if (abyte == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     xxx");
            }
            byteList.Add((byte)abyte);
            if (abyte == ItchConstants.TLF)
                break;
        }
        MessageData = byteList.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("End ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: " + LbTime.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("F0"));
    }

   public static GetMessage(NetworkStream tcpStream)
    {
        lock (TcpLock)
        {
            int abyte = tcpStream.ReadByte();
            try
            {
                ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF(tcpStream);
                //Do stuff with received data
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Start ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 0
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 199
              Pre ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 199
End ReadCompleteMessageUntilTLF: 199
```

However, I know from wireshark that the message arrived in 1 packet.

What could be causing this delay?

Comment: why are you doing that sleep loop. Its totally unneeded. The Read will block until there is data

Comment: I agree. I only put it in to see if it helped. This issue is the same whether it is in or not.

Comment: Because I am looking for a delimiting character.

Comment: @pm100 You removed your comment? I added higher loop code as requested.

Comment: Is it always the last byte that has the delay?

Comment: Is your Stopwatch just the normal one or something from a library?

Comment: @HansPassant It may be a simple approach, but there is also a delimiter. I am looping until I find that.